# What do our scriptures say about naming a child?

Tags: scripture, customs

Do Hindu scriptures provide details on how to properly name a child?
If there are any do’s and don’ts. Is it really necessary to name child based on month or tithis?

Comment: Related: [Shall we name our girl children after the name of rivers?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27324/1049)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming of the child is an important ceremony in Hinduism.

As per scriptures, it is required to be performed when the child attains a particular age (in days).

> Manu Smriti **2.30. But let (the father perform or) cause to be
>   performed the Namadheya (the rite of naming the child), on the tenth
>   or twelfth (day after birth**), or on a lucky lunar day, in a lucky
>   muhurta, under an auspicious constellation.

The names should be chosen according to the Varna of the child.

> 2.31. Let (the first part of) a Brahmana’s name (denote something) auspicious, a Kshatriya’s be connected with power, and a Vaisya’s with
>   wealth, but a Sudra’s (express something) contemptible.
>
> 2.32. (The second part of) a Brahmana’s (name) shall be (a word) implying happiness, of a Kshatriya’s (a word) implying protection, of
>   a Vaisya’s (a term) expressive of thriving, and of a Sudra’s (an
>   expression) denoting service.
>
> 2.33. The names of women should be easy to pronounce, not imply anything dreadful, possess a plain meaning, be pleasing and
>   auspicious, end in long vowels, and contain a word of benediction

These are all the rules given in the Smritis.

According to astrology, depending on the birth Nakshtra, the names should be chosen.

For example, for someone born in **Ashwini** Nakshtra the name should start with the letters like **Chu, Cho, La** etc to be considered as auspicious... and so on. For Bharani Nakshtra born the names should be starting with Li, Lu etc..

The complete list is given in the following image which is taken from [this site](http://www.gomama247.com/baby-names-starting-letters-based-on-nakshatra.html/):

[image]

I do not have scriptural references for the above list for the time being.

Comment: But if we see on broader aspect, isn't the name already given before our birth?

Comment: Naming of the child is to be done after it's birth. @AkshayKumarS

Comment: That's correct but isn't the name already given to us before our birth in this world based on our deeds?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS, what are you talking about.. who has a name before they're born ?

Comment: Hmm. @ram I read in a astrology writer we are already given our names for this birth before we're born. That's why am trying to find reference to Hindu scriptures

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for your answer. Are astrology related scriptures part of smriti texts? If yes could you pls let me know name of that text.

Comment: I don't know from which astrological text the list is taken.. but it is commonly found in many websites.. I will add a reference if found. @Ketan